# Node.js - How to throttle and limit logic but not limiting main endpoint?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

The question might sound a little weird but I am not sure how to handle this specific issue.

I have a requests than does a few things and sends a response back to the client.
In this specific requests i am also doing something after the response is sent back to do some backround stuff. The issue is lying inside this piece of logic / functionality since it requests a third party public API that has a rate limit. Let's say i send 20 requests/s to this endpoint.

10 requests will be processed by the third party public API and processed correctly, but the last 10 requests will not be processed and will return a rate limit error.

My question is - How can I change this logic / endpoint to support my demands. Any feedback and suggestions is much appreciated.

```
// endpoint /get-data/
await doAlotOfLogicHere();

setTimeout(() => {
      // Do something after 1 seconds
      // This specific action can only take 10 requests / second
      controller.doSomething(req,res)
    }, 1000);

// Send response to client
res.status(200).send(data);
```

controller.doSomething()

```
exports.doSomething = (req,res) => {
await sendDataToPublicAPI();
}
```

Comment: Is your node-app distributed or is it running on a single host?

Comment: Running on single host.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a little big vague... Let me suggest something, though.

1. Push the user request to a queue (this would be a database table with the resource, payload and timestamp)
2. Fire it from a [schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) or [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)
3. Make little asynchronous request to check whether the response is avaiable
4. Fetch the result data. It's best if you can cache it in your own database